# Javascript modification, Sum in output with discount on more selection

Tags: javascript

Code:

```
function totalIt() {
  var input = document.getElementsByName("product");
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].checked) {
      total += parseFloat(input[i].value);
    }
  }
  document.getElementsByName("total")[0].value = "₹" + total.toFixed(2);
}
```

***Conditions**:*

No discount on first select

50% discount on 2nd selection

After 3rd selection, each has 25% discount

***Expected Output:***
Each check(box)'s value is 100,

- on selection 1, Output = 100 (No discount)
- on selection 2, Output = 150 (50% discount in 2nd selection)
- on selection 3, Output = 175 (50% discount in 2nd, 25% discount on 3rd selection)
- on selection 4, Output = 200 (50% discount in 2nd, * 25% discount on 3rd selection selection)
- on selection, Output = 225 (50% discount in 2nd, 25% discount on 3rd selection selection)

Comment: [Javascript code modification in SUM and Discount on more selection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70389435) + [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBCfr.jpg). It seems you made a new account to post the same question.

Comment: Please do NOT RE-ASK a closed question.

Comment: Not only that, I already gave you a study list

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, i haven’t test it yet but i think it is working

```
function totalIt() {
  var input = document.getElementsByName("product");
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].checked) {
     var val = parseFloat(input[i].value);
     //second checkbox
     var discount = 0;
     if(i == 1){
        discount = val * 50 / 100;
     }

     //third checkbox and above 
     if(i > 1){
         discount = val * 25 / 100;
     }
      total += val - discount;
    }
  }
  document.getElementsByName("total")[0].value = "₹" + total.toFixed(2);
}
```